# Problemas com Repositório Remoto em Equipe Bitbucket

Tags: git, ubuntu, bitbucket

Criei um **Team** no bitbuckt, e criei um **Project** para este Team e neste Project eu criei um **Repositório**. Adicionei ao Team, uma chave ssh que criei na minha máquina (Ubuntu), porém ao realizar o `git clone` copiando a url de ssh tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Gostaria de saber como eu posso fazer para criar uma chave publica específica para este **Team**, pois eu não gostaria de ter que passa para a minha equipe a  chave ssh global (com acesso a todos os repositórios do bitbucket).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se a mensagem for está aqui:

[image: git clone user@bitbucket.org:user/gofileserver.git]

Possivelmente você não colocou sua chave **id_rsa.pub** no **"Access keys"** do bitbucket.org no local correto. No bitbucket as vezes confunde um pouco, você tem projetos e repositórios e algumas vezes podemos confundir com isto.

Confere se sua chave está realmente no repositório que deseja fazer o git clone.

Quando logar no bitbucket vc terá como escolher entre projeto ou repositório e suas urls para acessar o **"Settings"** onde fica as chaves seria algo parecido com as urls abaixo:

**Username**

bitbucket.org/username/repositorio/admin/access-keys/

Ou **Team**
bitbucket.org/seuteam/repositorio/admin/access-keys/

Você vai em projetos ou em repositórios para aplicar o seu **Settings**.

Mas antes é claro da uma conferida se gerou corretamente as chaves de acesso.

**Em linux ficaria assim:**

1) criando chave de acesso

```
$ ssh-keygen 
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa):
```

Pressione a tecla Enter ou Return para aceitar a localização padrão.

2) Caminhos diferentes na criação do seu id_rsa

Para criar uma chave com um nome ou caminho diferente do padrão, especifique o caminho completo para a chave. Por exemplo, para criar uma chave chamada my-new-ssh-key, insira um caminho como o mostrado no prompt:

```
$ ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa): /Users/emmap1/.ssh/my-new-ssh-key
```

3) Digite e volte a inserir uma frase secreta quando solicitado.

O comando cria sua identidade padrão com suas chaves públicas e privadas. Toda a interação parecerá semelhante à seguinte:

```
ssh-keygen
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa):
Created directory '/Users/emmap1/.ssh'.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /Users/emmap1/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
4c:80:61:2c:00:3f:9d:dc:08:41:2e:c0:cf:b9:17:69 emmap1@myhost.local
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|*o+ooo.          |
|.+.=o+ .         |
|. *.* o .        |
| . = E o         |
|    o . S        |
|   . .           |
|     .           |
|                 |
|                 |
+-----------------+
```

4) Liste o conteúdo de ~ / .ssh para ver os arquivos de chaves

```
$ ls ~/.ssh
id_rsa id_rsa.pub
```

Agora basta usar o comando abaixo para copiar e colocar sua chave pública no bitbucket

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

[image: Copiando e Colando no bitbucket]

Agora para testar se tudo ocorreu bem faça o seguinte no seu console linux.

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org

conq: logged in as emmap1.
You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

Se sua mensagem for igual acima é porque deu algo errado possivelmente sua chave no bitbucket não está configurada corretamente.

A mensagem de comando informa qual das suas contas Bitbucket pode fazer login com essa chave.

Se o comando acima enviar uma mensagem como está

```
authenticated via a deploy key.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.

This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:

username/seurepositorio: name1-chave -- email@email.com

team-2017/repositorio: name2-chave -- email@email.com
```

A mensagem informa exatamente quais repositório foi clonado para sua máquina e seu acesso.

Se tiver usando Windows ou Mac sugiro acessar este link https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Comment: Funcionou, muito obrigado Jefferson... Agora me diz uma coisa, para cada repositório que eu criar, eu tenho que refazer todo o procedimento, inclusive criar outra chave ssh na minha máquina? 
Neste caso, é uma boa prática que o nome da chave ssh tenha o mesmo nome do meu respectivo repositório?

Comment: No bitbucket você consegue colocar as chaves no projeto, team e no usuário do team.

Comment: No bitbucket você consegue colocar as chaves no projeto, team e no usuário do team. Faz alguns testes para sua realidade para ver qual adequa melhor para você. Quando você adiciona a key direto no usuário ele terá acesso a todos os repositórios.

Ao criar um repositório você tem a opção de inserir a chave para cada usuário, ou você pode tentar colocar no team/projects que teoricamente iria colocar uma única vez para cada projeto mas tem que testar e ver se a opção não é paga. Você não precisa criar varias chaves em sua máquina rever sua política de acesso no bitbucket como descrevi acima.